# Constructing a list that includes a leading zero (01,02,03 ... 55, 56, etc.)

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting

I am constructing a list for use in file operations. Say I want to create `list` which contains values from 01 to 87. The kicker is that the first nine integers need to keep a value of `01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11.. etc.`

So if I create `list=Range[87]` I generate a list of integers. Whenever I'm trying to then replace values with '01', etc. they become strings. If they are integers, they revert back to the single value. Ideally, I need a list that I can feed through `Do[]`.

Is there a quick way to create a list that uses the two digit form the whole time?

FWIW, the specific application of this that I have a list of files i.e. `{1997-01-page100.jpeg, 1997-01-page101,jpeg, <<33 379>>, 1997-87-page9.jpeg, 1997-87-page10,jpeg}`. I'm using the following command to generate specific lists of the sub-file using `importlist=FileNames["1997-"<>ToString[x]<>"-*.jpeg"]` but am being thrown off by the zero in front of the single-digit file number.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I always use `IntegerString` for this (I also number my files in a similar way):

```
In[1]:= IntegerString[#, 10, 2] & /@ Range[87]

Out[1]= {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", \
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", \
"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", \
"33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", \
"44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", \
"55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", \
"66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", \
"77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87"}
```

I think this is the most convenient solution, as it's built-in and doesn't require any additional effort to get it working.

Comment: Yup. +1 (I'm never going to catch up on points...)

Comment: Szabolcs's Kryptonite --- lol.

Comment: Oh my goodness, it *is* your Kryptonite -- you deleted the comment!  Double lol.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "I'm never going to catch up on points..." — LOL

Comment: @rm-rf Marriage: the ultimate sabotage. xD

Answer (score 7):

Put a zero to the left of each number, but only keep the two rightmost characters:

```
StringTake["0" <> ToString[#], -2] & /@ Range[87]
```

> ```
> {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10",
>  "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21",
>  "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32",
>  "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43",
>  "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54",
>  "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65",
>  "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76",
>  "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87"}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use NumberForm (although the IntegerString solution is nicer in this case). Here the integer is padded with two zeroes.

```
Table[ToString[NumberForm[i, 2, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}]], {i, 1, 
  10}]
```

> {"001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010"}

An example for adding numerical indices to a list of file names:

```
files = {"a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt"};
MapIndexed[
 ToString[NumberForm[#2[[1]], 2, NumberPadding -> {"0", ""}]] <> 
   "_" <> #1 &, files]
```

> {"001_a.txt", "002_b.txt", "003_c.txt"}

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
StringJoin /@ Map[ToString, PadLeft[#, 2] & /@ 
  IntegerDigits[Range[87]], {2}]
```

Note that the result is a list of strings, but I guess you want strings to form the file names anyway.