# Why does the PlotStyle not apply globaly when I plot multiple data files

Tags: plotting, import

I have several data files which contain columns of data. All my files follow the same format data001.out, data002.out, ... , data00n.out. I want to import and plot all of them simultaneously. In particular, I use only the first two columns of the data files for my plot. I wrote this simple Mathematica code:

```
SetDirectory["..."];

dataAll = {};

Do[
   data = ReadList["data00" <> ToString[NumberForm[i, 2, NumberPadding 
   -> {"0", ""}]] <> ".out", Number, 
   RecordLists -> True];
   pdata = Table[{data[[j, 1]], data[[j, 2]]}, {j, 1, Length[data]}];
   AppendTo[dataAll, Flatten[pdata]];
  , {i, 1, 50}
]   

S0 = ListPlot[dataAll, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
RotateLabel -> False, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.01]}, 
PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

I am wondering, if there is a simpler or even more correct way to perform this task. Perhaps, the `Do` loop needs improvement.

I noticed that the `PlotStyle` in `ListPlot` does not apply to all points of the dataAll list. Even if I determine the color (black) and the size, the output contains several colors ans sizes. Where is the mistake?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3165/5

Comment: @rm-rf The first issue is solved. However, the second issue regarding the global `PlotStyle` remains unsolved.

Comment: Well, then please edit your question and focus only on that. Do not ask multiple, unrelated questions in a single post. Also, your example is not reproducible... you allude to a set of `data*.out` files that reside on your disk and we have no way of knowing what's in them and what the issues with your plot are. Please include a **minimal example** that users can copy-paste-evaluate to see your problem. Use simple functions like `Sin[x]` or `RandomReal` if a random list would suffice.

Comment: If you want all the points to be black and equal size, then define the plot style in this way: `PlotStyle -> {{Black, PointSize[0.01]}}`. Note the extra {} brackets. Without those, *Mathematica* cycles between black and automatically chosen colors with the size defined by `PointSize`.

Comment: @VLC Thank you very much! Problem solved.

Comment: I recommend `IntegerString` over `ToString` and `NumberForm`. `"data" <> IntegerString[i, 10, 3] <> ".out",` is simpler.

Comment: @VLC May I suggest you to post an answer?

Comment: @belisarius Done, although I'm not sure that this question deserves to be kept open.

Comment: @VLC Thanks, upvoted

Comment: @VLC I totally agree; I have all my answers so it should be considered closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you plot several list of points and you want to define the same style for all the points you have to take care of how you insert the style in the `PlotStyle` option.

```
data = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10] + i, {i, 8}];
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[.02]}]
```

[image]

In this case, the `PlotStyle` was not defined properly. *Mathematica* interprets this input as apply `Black` to the first list of points, apply `PointSize[.02]` to the second list; if there are more lists, cycle between the two styles.

To apply both options to all lists of points, you need to enclose the options between additional curly brackets. In this case *Mathematica* applies both the color and the size to the first list of points and then re-cycles these options for all the other lists of points.

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {{Black, PointSize[.02]}}]
```

[image]

If you need to define separate styles for different lists of plots, you need to insert a list of lists containing the style options, and remember that *Mathematica* will always cycle through this list.

```
ListPlot[data, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Black, PointSize[.02]}, {Red, PointSize[.02]}}]
```

[image]