# Is there a manual way to generate a string of zeroes with a 2 at the end?

Tags: string-manipulation, prime-numbers

How do I get mathematica to display 33141015 zeroes and a 2

I've tried using

2*10^-33141016

but it just gives me scientific notation

Is there a manual way to generate a string that looks like this:

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...2

It's very important to my work I'm doing on finding the next prime with over (10^(10^8)) digits

Comment: Are you serious? To "Display" such a thing would result in a string that was literally miles long... As far as "a manual way", sure - hold down the zero key. At normal auto-repeat rates, should be done in a month or so. In any case, I'll let you know when 1*^33141015 + 2 updates on my display. In about a week...

Comment: something like `StringJoin@ConstantArray["0", 1000] <> "2"`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructing a list that includes a leading zero (01,02,03 ... 55, 56, etc.)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/constructing-a-list-that-includes-a-leading-zero-01-02-03-55-56-etc). Try `IntegerString[2, 10, whatever]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IntegerString[2,10,33141015+1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
PaddedForm[2, 33141015, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]
```

Will do it, well, that's the command to do it. Not responsible for monitor bursting into flames, etc.